# Using Case statement with nested SELECT in a dataset to then populate a parameter drop-down SSRS

Tags: select, reporting-services, parameters, dataset, nested

I am able to populate a parameter drop-down in SSRS that grabs a list of activities from a dataset.  Though the issue I have is within the data there is a activitylabel field that is only contained in the dimact table and when any activity has a label value of 'versional' I want a case statement to replace it with the name of the parent activity instead of the default child activity name.  The fields that join up the data are activity_pk and activityfk and the field to get the correct parent is prntactfk.  Below is an example of data where I want the 2 Test Course rows to become one with the DISTINCT used in the query within the drop-down.

```
Example Data: (Name - Label) 
CourseA-Course (Not Versional so leave alone) 
Test Course-Versional  (Parent is Test Course Parent) 
Test Course (1.1)-Versional (Parent is Test Course Parent) 
CourseB-Document (Not Versional so leave alone)
```

Query that works in SQL without the use of the dimact1.ActivityLabel = 'Versional:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT act1.activityname
FROM  act1
INNER JOIN dimact1 on dimact1.ActivityFK = act1.Activity_PK
WHERE 
CASE 
        WHEN dimact1.ActivityLabel = 'Versional' 
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT dimact2.PrntActFK
                FROM dimact2
        WHERE dimact2.activitylabel = 'Versional'
        AND dimact2.PrntActFK = act1.Activity_PK
    ) THEN 1
END = 1
ORDER BY act1.activityname ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically in situations like this one would `LEFT JOIN` to the parent table then use a `CASE` or `COALESCE` to choose between the parent and child values.

So for data like:

```
create table Courses
(
  ID int
  , name varchar(100)
  , label varchar(100)
  , parentID int
)

insert into Courses
values
(1,'Test Course Parent','Test Course Parent',null)
, (2,'CourseA','Course',null)
, (3,'CourseB','Document',null)
, (4,'Test Course','Versional',1)
, (5,'Test Course (1.1)','Versional',1)
```

You could use a query like:

```
select distinct case when c.Label = 'Versional' then p.name
  else c.name
  end as name
from Courses c
  left join Courses p on c.parentID = p.ID
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31367/2).

Hopefully this gets you on the right track. I confess I found your example a bit hard to follow, so if you need more information please supply some sample data and your required results.